# Showing that $\int \liminf_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x) dx \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int f_{n}(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I don't know why, but I find this problem counter intuitive to me.

Prove that if $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable nonnegative functions on a measurable set $E$ and $f(x)=\liminf_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x)$, then

$$\int_{E}  f(x) dx \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} f_{n}(x) dx.$$

Can someone outline the proof for me please?

Comment: Fatou's lemma - proof is givein in Wikipedia's article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma#Standard_statement_of_Fatou.27s_lemma

Comment: haha, how stupid i am. Thx.

Comment: Alex, maybe you'd care to type up an answer...?

Answer (score 2):

This is called [Fatou's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma). You can also read the proof in Terry Tao's [lecture notes](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/245a-notes-3-integration-on-abstract-measure-spaces-and-the-convergence-theorems/#more-4200). (See Corollary 16 on that page.) There is also a very nice remark for this lemma there.

For me, the key point is the *definition* of $\liminf$.

I am a little surprised that the book in which you learn measure theory does not mention the name of this statement.